# Ayuda, batch para hacer ping a distintas IP

Tags: batch

Quiero hacer un pequeño batch donde pueda hacer ping a distintas IP y solo me muestre los datos enviados/recibidos/perdidos, se puede hacer? o estoy soñando

algo asi como:

```
IP         Enviados     Recibidos       Perdidos      
172.0.0.1     15            15              0
127.0.0.2     0             0               12
```

ya tengo un batch donde almaceno direcciones IP en un array...

```
@echo off
:inicio
cls
set /a ip = 0
set /a c = 0
color 30
set var=0
echo.
echo ===================================
echo Ping Pong
echo ===================================
echo.
echo -----------------------------------
echo 1)Ingresar Direccion IP
echo 2)Salir
echo -----------------------------------
echo.
set /p var=^> Seleccione una opcion 1-2:

if %var%==1 goto op1
if %var%==2 goto salir
::error
echo. Intente de nuevo.
pause
goto inicio

:op1
cls
echo.
color 0A
set /p ip[%c%]=^> Ingresar una IP:
set /a c = %c%+1
echo.
echo 1)Ingresar Nueva IP
echo 2)Procesar
echo 3)Volver
echo 4)Salir
set /p var=^> :
if %var%==1 goto op1
if %var%==2 goto op2
if %var%==3 goto inicio
if %var%==4 goto salir

:op2
cls
echo.
color 0A
SET /a c = %c%-1
echo ========================================
for /l %%n in (0,1,%c%) do (
call echo %%ip[%%n]%%
)
echo ========================================
pause
goto inicio

:salir
@exit
```

pero me perdí un poco, alguien un empujón para poder continuar por favor...

gracias

Comment: Los datos/líneas aparecerían en secuencia? Primero `172.0.0.1     15            15              0`, despues `127.0.0.2     0             0               12` etc. O pretendes que aparezca y se actualice simultaneamente?

Comment: Pretendía que aparezca simultáneamente y se actualicen casa segundo...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, es muy chapucero, pero: Puedes ponerle el codigo necesario a otro batch desde un batch (ahora lo explico) para hacer un bucle con una secuencia de código que le haga un ping por vez a cada IP, i vuelta empezar. Puedes establecer a cuantas IP le haces ping añadiendo otra línea al batch secundario.

Batch 1 (controlador):

```
@echo off
@echo off >> batch2.bat
rem Aquí creamos el batch secundario, poniéndole la cabezera. 
:bucle >> batch2.bat 
rem Para el bucle dentro del batch2.bat
:again
CHOICE /C 12 /M "Añadir IP (1) Ejecutar (2) Salir (3)"
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto OP1)
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto OP2) 
if %errorlevel%==3 (exit)

:OP1
set /p nwIP = NuevaIP=
ping -n count 1 %NuevaIP% >> batch2.bat 
goto again

:OP2
goto bucle >> batch2.bat
call batch2.bat
goto again
```

Esto es en caso de que quieras hacerlo en bucle. Se podría hacer con numero limitado, pero el codigo se complicaria un poquito más (o se le debería añadir un for).

Espero que haya servido. Necesitas la versión limitada? Yo de todas formas recomiendo hacelro así.

Adiós!